# eclipse fails to export apk as a result of progaurd error 1 code

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

this is what I get when I try to export apk file with proguard on. if I switch it off it exports the apk file. please not that isn't all of the trace because the rest would exceed the character limit

```
 [2014-09-11 20:35:39 - Simplify] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatKitKat: can't find referenced method 'int getLiveRegion()' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
    [2014-09-11 20:35:39 - Simplify] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatKitKat: can't find referenced method 'void setLiveRegion(int)' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
    [2014-09-11 20:35:39 - Simplify] Warning: android.support.v4.widget.ListPopupWindowCompatKitKat: can't find referenced method 'android.view.View$OnTouchListener createDragToOpenListener(android.view.View)' in class android.widget.ListPopupWindow
    [2014-09-11 20:35:39 - Simplify] Warning: android.support.v4.widget.PopupMenuCompatKitKat: can't find referenced method 'android.view.View$OnTouchListener getDragToOpenListener()' in class android.widget.PopupMenu
    [2014-09-11 20:35:39 - Simplify]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
    [2014-09-11 20:35:39 - Simplify] Warning: there were 193 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
    [2014-09-11 20:35:39 - Simplify]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
    [2014-09-11 20:35:39 - Simplify] Warning: there were 43 unresolved references to program class members.
    [2014-09-11 20:35:39 - Simplify]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
    [2014-09-11 20:35:39 - Simplify]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
    [2014-09-11 20:35:39 - Simplify]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
    [2014-09-11 20:35:39 - Simplify]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
    [2014-09-11 20:35:39 - Simplify] Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. The safest choice is to resolve the Proguard errors, for which the troubleshooting guide is [here](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html).

The second option is to add `-ignorewarnings` to your proguard configuration, which will still print the warnings, but will allow the build to succeed anyway. This might lead to runtime errors when your application can't find some of the classes/methods/fields that the proguard errors warned you about, or it might not, as these errors can also be caused by differences between android runtime versions etc.

Answer (score -1):

Installing new eclipse version resolved all my problems